About the solutions of $ \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2 $
I already posted this question on MSE.
Using theorem $IV$ from this article, it is possible to prove that when $p$ is a prime such that $p ≡ 3\bmod4$,  $x ≢ y\bmod{p}$ and $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, then the equation
$$
\dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2
$$ ever admits solutions for some integers $\{a, b\}$ (see proof below).
I want to know how $\{a, b\}$ can be expressed as a function of $\{x, y\}$: the case $p=3$ is easy as
$$
\begin{align}
a &= \dfrac{x-y}{2}\\ 
b &= \dfrac{x+y}{2}
\end{align}
$$
(of course not all the solutions have this form).
With the great help of Will Jagy on MSE, the closed form for the following cases are
$$
\begin{align}
p &= 7\\
a &= \frac{ (x-y)  (2x^2 + 3xy + 2y^2 )}{  2},\\
b &= \frac{xy(x+y)}{2},\\
p &= 11\\
a &= \frac{( x-y) (2x^4 + 3x^3  y  + x^2  y^2 + 3  x  y^3 + 2  y^4)}{  2},\\ 
b &= \frac{ xy(x+y)(x^2 - xy+y^2)}{  2}\\
p &= 19\\
a &= \frac{ (x-y)  (2x^8 + 3x^7y - x^6y^2 + 2x^5y^3 + 7x^4y^4 + 2x^3y^5 - x^2y^6 + 3xy^7 + 2y^8 )}{ 2},\\ 
b &= \frac{  x  y  (x +y) ( x^2 -xy +y^2)(x^4 - x^2 y^2 + y^4   )}{  2}
\end{align}
$$
What can be said in general?
I guess it is possible to restate the problem in terms of cyclotomic binary forms: if we define
$$
f(k) = y^{\phi(k)} \Phi_k(x/y)
$$ where $ \phi(k)$ is Euler's phi function and $ \Phi_k(x/y) $ is the $k$-th cyclotomic polynomial, so that
$$
f(p) = \dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y}
$$ and
$$
\begin{align}
f(7) &= a^2 + 7\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)}{2} \right )^2\\
f(11) &= a^2 + 11\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)f(6)}{2} \right )^2\\
f(19) &= a^2 + 19\left (\dfrac{xyf(2)f(6)f(12)}{2} \right )^2
\end{align}
$$
Proof: when $(x - y) ≢ {0}\bmod{p}$ then we have that
$$
\dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = P(p)
$$
where $P(p)$ is the arithmetic primitive factor of $ (x^p - y^p) $ defined in that article (p. $175$). With other considerations we can say that each one of those primitive prime factors is of the form $(2k_i p+1)$ where $k_i$ $∈ N$.
Now $q\mid{a^2+pb^2} $, with $q\nmid p$, iff $ \left(\frac{-p}{q}\right) = 1$ and equivalently
$$
q ≡ \{q_1, q_2, q_3,\ldots\}\bmod{4p}
$$
(see corollary $1.19$ in David Cox's book Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$), so being $q=2k_i p+1$, we have just $q_1=1$ and $q_2 = 2p+1$. Using that $p ≡ 3\bmod4$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{-p}{2p+1}\right) = 1
$$ and so
$$
\dfrac{x^p - y^p}{x - y} = a^2+pb^2
$$ ever admits solutions for some integers $\{a, b\}$.

as I had indicated, the fact that a prime $q  \equiv 1 \pmod p$  is no guarantee of a representation as $q = u^2 + p v^2$  or as $q = s^2 + st + \frac{1+p}{4} t^2,$   the parent form. So I don't see your last paragraph as a proof of your conjecture.  For $p=23$  the two binary forms agree for this purpose.     I've got a few dozen primes expressible as your $q =\frac{x^{23} - y^{23}}{x-y}.$   By factoring $x^3 - x + 1 \pmod q$  I can tell whether $q = u^2 + 23 v^2.$  So far, all succeed. See http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

The thing about 7, 11, 19 is class number one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number

What does "ever admits solutions" mean? (Sorry, I don't want to have to read the proof to find out.)

@DanielAsimov  it is an older usage of the word ever, now largely obsolete. I looked up the etymology, it all makes sense... I would have written "always,"  or perhaps just omitted the word ever.

@WillJagy Thank you for pointing that out.I just intended that because the primitive prime factors have the form $ (2k_i p+1) $, when you take their $ \bmod{4p} $ you have just 2 possible outcomes $q_i= {1, 2p+1} $ and in the case $ p ≡ 3\bmod4 $, for both it holds $ \left(\frac{-p}{q_i}\right) = 1 $ (it's just a way to prove that $ \left(\frac{-p}{2k_i p+1}\right) = 1 $ alway hold, but maybe there is a simpler one).
Do you think that the reason underlying the close form cases is that they are Heegner numbers? It would be possible to find something similar for $p=43$ and others?
Thank you

Andre Weil,  in Number Theory: An approach through History, on pages 336 and 337, says that Gauss proved this. Calling $F= \frac{x^p - y^p}{x-y}$ splits into two factors in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {\pm p}) ,$ leading to polynomials $P,Q$ with half-integer coefficients  and $F = P^2 - p Q^2$  when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$   but $F = P^2 + p Q^2$  when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$

it's in the Disquisitiones, articles 124   and 357. In my translation  pages 82 and 439-440.

Values for $a$ and $b$ as polynomials in $x,y$, when they exist, correspond to factorization of $\frac{x^p+y^2}{x+y}$ over the imaginary field $K_p:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ of the form:
$$\frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y} = (a(x,y)+\sqrt{-p}b(x,y))\cdot (a(x,y)-\sqrt{-p}b(x,y)).$$
For $p\equiv1\pmod4$, we can similarly work in $K_p:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ and look for factorization of the form:
$$\frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y} = (a(x,y)+\sqrt{p}b(x,y))\cdot (a(x,y)-\sqrt{p}b(x,y)).$$
This Sage code (updated 2024-06-30) factors $\frac{x^p+1}{x+1}$ over $K_p$ and converts the result into the required form, and reports the (univariate) polynomials $a(x,1)$ and $b(x,1)$. As an example, it reports $a$ and $b$ for all primes below $100$.
Example for $p=23$:
$$a = (x + 1) \cdot (x^{10} - \frac{3}{2} x^{9} - x^{8} + 5 x^{7} - \frac{17}{2} x^{6} + \frac{21}{2} x^{5} - \frac{17}{2} x^{4} + 5 x^{3} - x^{2} - \frac{3}{2} x + 1),$$
$$b= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x - 1) \cdot x \cdot (x^{8} + x^{5} - x^{4} + x^{3} + 1).$$

Andre Weil,  in Number Theory: An approach through History, on pages 336 and 337, says that Gauss proved this. Calling $F= \frac{x^p - y^p}{x-y}$ splits into two factors in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {\pm p}) ,$ leading to polynomials $P,Q$ with half-integer coefficients  and $F = P^2 - p Q^2$  when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$   but $F = P^2 + p Q^2$  when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$

in my English translation of the Disquisitiones Gauss  announces the result in article 124, page 82, then gives detail in article 357, pages 439-440

@MaxAlekseyev Thank you so much! I tried with a few other cases, but it seems that $b$ is not factorizable in terms of cyclotomic polynomials, like I showed for the cases $p=7, 11, 19$, that just happened by chance or is there an underlying reason? Thank you!

@WillJagy: Nice find! I suspected that this subject should be well studied.

@user967210: I think it was just by chance. The factors of $b$, besides $x-1$, are generally palindromic but do not necessarily divide $\Phi_p$.

@MaxAlekseyev Thank you! Can I just ask you one last thing? How do I need to modify your Sage code to show the cases $ p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $ for $ \frac{x^p - y^p}{x-y} = P^2 - p Q^2 $? I tried something, but I'm new to sage. Thanks

@Max  I put two expositions in my answer, a chapter by Cox and a survey by Savitt, which appears to give a complete proof   of the $a^2 \pm p b^2$  thing.

@user967210: I've updated the code in my answer to handle all odd primes.

Friday, June 28.  I found a nice exposition by David Savitt
https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~web401/steve.gauss17gon.pdf
from which this is page 32
David A. Cox, in Galois Theory,  gives an account of Gauss's theory of periods
http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf
Cox does only a few examples,  but Reuschle filled a book with nothing but.
https://archive.org/details/tafelncomplexer00unkngoog/page/n7/mode/2up

The first few  cases where $  z = \frac{x^{23} - y^{23}}{x-y} $  turned out to be prime. I wrote some software to solve $z = u^2 + 23 v^2$  in a reasonable time.
x: 2 y: -1 z: 2796203  z prime ? 2   
990^2 + 23 * 281^2 =  2796203 

x: 3 y: -1 z: 23535794707  z prime ? 2  
 118750^2 + 23 * 20253^2  = 23535794707

x: 5 y: 3 z: 5960417405949649  z prime ? 1   ?
  38872207^2 + 23 * 13908660^2   = 5960417405949649

x: 6 y: 5 z: 777809294098524691  z prime ? 1 ? 
   827130254^2  + 23 * 63815235^2   = 777809294098524691

x: 7 y: -1 z: 3421093417510114543  z prime ? 1?
   1755643660^2 + 23 *  121370571^2   = 3421093417510114543

x: 7 y: -2 z: 3040971926676589439  z prime ? 1? 
 1438562808^2  + 23 *  205522555^2   = 3040971926676589439

x: 10 y: 1 z: 11111111111111111111111  z prime ? 1    ?
 102063239244^2 + 23 * 5493895055^2   = 11111111111111111111111  


Wow! Thank you so much for the reference!
